# Spring MVC webapp link to excel document and rename it

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a question about whether or not something is possible. I have a spring mvc webapp that will have a button that links to an external website which returns an Excel document. The name of the excel document returned is rubbish and I would like to rename the document as it comes in before the user is prompted to save.

Is this possible using spring mvc. I'm on a really old version. The version compatible with Java 1.4.2.

So far I'm thinking that I'll extend org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController, override handleRequestInternal and then do something like this....

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

RedirectUrlBuilder urlBuilder = new RedirectUrlBuilder();
urlBuilder.setServerName(batchServerName);
urlBuilder.setPort(Integer.parseInt(batchServerPort));
urlBuilder.setContextPath(batchReportRoot);
urlBuilder.setServletPath(reportNameServletPath);
urlBuilder.setPathInfo(reportNamePathInfo);
urlBuilder.setScheme(HTTP);

String transitionUrl = urlBuilder.getUrl();
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(transitionUrl));

return modelAndView;
```

But how do i take it further to rename the document as it comes in etc...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps another approach you might consider is that you have a Controller implementation that proxies the request onto the external website. Rather than interacting with the external website directly, your users interact with your Controller. This will give you the opportunity to re-name the file before it is served to your users. It also means that should things change in the future, you only need to change the implementation of your Controller.

So a proposed work flow could be:

1. User clicks link to your controller /downloadExcelReport
2. The request is handled by ExcelReportController
3. ExcelReportController makes an HTTP request to the external website and fetches the Excel document
4. Before returning the Excel report to your user, ExcelReportController sets the correct HTTP headers to ensure that the file is named according to what you need.

This way you're only providing a normal Controller implementation rather than having to override the internals of Spring.